# How to concatenate a character to a SQL string in a preparedstatemenet

Tags: java, sql

When I concatenate a character namely tid
to this string in Java. I will get
where sc.CategoryCode = C
But I actually need
where sc.CategoryCode = 'C'
when I add a single quote both on the start
and on the end side of tid
like 
where sc.CategoryCode = '" + tid + "'";
I'll get
where sc.CategoryCode = 'C"
And it seems very strange. 
Thanks
Jack

```
String str = "select sc.* from SubCategory sc"
           + "  where sc.CategoryCode = " + tid;
```

Comment: You're talking about PreparedStatement, but you're not using it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't build up your SQL like this - you should use parameterized SQL instead:

```
// TODO: Closing the statement etc
String sql = "select sc.* from SubCategory sc where sc.CategoryCode = ?";
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setString(tid); // Or statement.setString(String.valueOf(tid))
ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery();
```

Reasons for using parameterized SQL:

- Avoiding [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)
- Avoiding unnecessary (and potentially problematic) conversions, particularly with dates/times
- Keeping your code (the SQL) separate from the data (the parameters), which aids readability

Comment: Another reason if you are concerned about performance: so the database server doesn't have to constantly recompile your sql statement

Answer (score 0):

I  don't know if you are working with jdbc template... i post you an example.

select :

```
private static final String SELECT_SANCIONS_GIM = "SELECT * " + "FROM "
            + Constants.T_GPT_V_DETALL_SANCIO_GIM + " WHERE "
            + Constants.EXP_ID_ENS + " =:idEns" + " AND " + Constants.EXP_ANY_EXP
            + " =:anyExp" + " AND " + Constants.EXP_NUM_EXP + " =:numExp" + " AND "
            + Constants.ACRONIM_EXP + " =:acr";
```

//=:variable

I use Stringbuilder, take a look:

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.append(SELECT_SANCIONS_GIM);
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();           

    parameters.addValue("idEns",clauExpedient.getIdEns() );
    parameters.addValue("anyExp",clauExpedient.getAnyExp());
    parameters.addValue("numExp",clauExpedient.getNumExp() );
    parameters.addValue("acr", clauExpedient.getAcrProcediment());
```

I hope it helps.